# Cannot Launch Activity in Android Library Module

Tags: android, android-activity, module, android-studio

To my Android app project, I added a module which contains an activity named "SampleDataMenuActivity". There is nothing special to this activity - it's added using the "New Module" -> "Android Library" dialog in Android Studio and includes the "Hello World" code generated by Android Studio.

The AndroidManifest.xml of the app includes (from the module):

```
<activity
    android:name="com.sample.sampledata.SampleDataMenuActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SampleDataMenuActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

In the build.gradle of the app:

```
dependencies {
    (...)
    compile project(':sampledata')
}
```

In the settings.gradle of the project:

```
include ':sampledata', ':app'
```

In the main activity of my app, I want to navigate to an activity in the module using:

```
startActivity(new Intent("com.sample.sampledata.SampleDataMenuActivity"));
```

The project builds just fine, but when I tap the button that should take me to the activity in the module it fails, reporting:

```
android.content.ActivityNoFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent ( act=com.sample.sampledata.SampleDataMenuActivity )
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the mistake, and perhaps I should remove the question. But as it was upvoted, somone else might be interested in this answer:

The manifest should state:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.sample.sampledata.SampleDataMenuActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.sample.sampledata.SampleDataMenuActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Why is there <action android:name="com.sample.sampledata.SampleDataMenuActivity" /> in the <intent-filter>? Just curious. I kind of want to do the same thing.

Comment: There are probably more qualified people to answer this but I will give it a try: When starting an activity using `startActivity(new Intent("<action_name>")` the app looks for an intent that matches the action name, and then launches the corresponding activity. For launching an activity, you can give it any name you want to but, to my understanding, using the full path of the activity class is considered good practice and makes your code more readable and maintainable..

Comment: The code in the above answer and question looks similar. What is the difference then ?

Comment: Category `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` is typically used for intents starting an activity. The activity name given in the question is meaningless. It was simply a typo or copy/paste issue.