# Cannot start another activity through super activity by overriding startActivity(Intent)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a, Activity class `A` which overrides the `startActivity(intent)`. Basically it just checks the intent and then pass it to the super activity by calling `super.startActivity(intent)`. This activity is in a module.

Now I created a project and added this module. I have an activity class inside this project named `B` which extends `A`. Now `B` calls activity `C` within the same project. If `B` does not extend `A` it can call `C`. But whenever it extends `A`, nothing happens. What might be the problem. I tried to print the current class and called class in the super activity `A` and I can see that it the intent is OK. But whenever I want to call `C` via `A` through this method nothing happens.

Here is my code snippet.

```
public  class A extends Activity{


    @Override
    public void startActivity(Intent intent)
    {



        //do something here. Not modifying the intent


        super.startActivity(intent);
      }
}
```

And in activity B,

```
public class B extends A 
{
  //somewhere in a button handler
  Intent intent = new Intent(B.this, C.class);
  startActivity(intent);
}
```

What I can see that from the code the `startActivity` inside `A` is called indeed. But when I pass the intent to super, nothing happens. But if `B` does not extend `A` everything works fine. It is to be noted that `A` is a library module.

while looking at logcat I do not see any errors,

```
D/TaskPersister(  826): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=279_task.xml
I/Tasker_Activity( 1181): Inside tasker activity
D/audio_hw_primary(  348): out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(1: low-latency-playback) kvpairs: routing=2
D/audio_hw_primary(  348): select_devices: out_snd_device(2: speaker) in_snd_device(0: none)
D/msm8974_platform(  348): platform_send_audio_calibration: sending audio calibration for snd_device(2) acdb_id(15)
E/ACDB-LOADER(  348): Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19
D/audio_hw_primary(  348): enable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
D/audio_hw_primary(  348): enable_audio_route: apply and update mixer path: low-latency-playback speaker
D/audio_hw_primary(  348): disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback speaker
D/audio_hw_primary(  348): disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
```

But I do not know what this means `E/ACDB-LOADER(  348): Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19`

It is to be noted that instead of a library I put the super Activity A inside the application project but the result is same.

Comment: my bad, typo. fixed it.

Comment: What are you doing in startActivity? Maybe this is not needed?

Comment: Well I am actually checking the the extras inside the intent. But this is not any issue, for example if I do nothing just send the intent using super.startActivity(intent), still nothing happens.

Comment: are there any warnings or errors in logcat?

Comment: I have updated my answer, none that seems noticeable.

Comment: I don't see any helpful errors or warnings. Try remove startActivity method temporary in A class and write if it works.

Comment: Try to replace `super.startActivity(intent);` with `getBaseContext().startActivity(intent);`

Comment: No it does not work.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977007/cannot-launch-activity-in-android-library-module

Comment: @krystian71115 yes at last getBaseContext() and getApplicationContext() both works but I had to set flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to the intent before calling it. Thanks a bunch. May be you can put it as a solution.