# How to invoke an Activity (belonging to a module) in another module in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, module

Here's the scenario : 
I have 2 modules (In Android Studio, File -> New -> New Module) in my single application.

1. Module A
2. Module B

Module A (Its not a library project. 
it's gradle starts with apply plugin: 'com.android.application').

Module B (which is also not a library module).

Inside module B, I need to invoke an Activity (say MainActivity) which belongs to module A.

**Module A manifest :**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abc.emergencycontacts">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">
<activity android:name=".EmergencyContactsActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Module B manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abc.secondaryactivity">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true">

        <activity android:name=".BaseAppActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

How do I achieve it?

Please note that I cannot add module A's dependency in module B, since module A is not a library module.

Awaiting your valuable response.

Comment: I don't exactly understand your scenario? Are you talking about two different applications?

Comment: @MuratK. Sorry to make it confusing. I'm talking about 2 different modules of a same application. Edited the question.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26977007/cannot-launch-activity-in-android-library-module

Comment: @MuratK. It doesn't. The link you suggested deals with communication between app and a module. What I'm dealing with is between 2 modules. app module is not involved.

Comment: I'm unable to refer (in module B) to the activity which lies in the module A since I can't add the dependency of module A in B's gradle since A is not a library.

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: No sorry, I have no experience in such a case.

Comment: I investigated this issue in the following article and proposed a practical solution. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77384164/10090030

Answer (score 2):

To launch any `Activity` from any application, you can just do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClassName("packageName", "className");
startActivity(intent);
```

You don't need to be able to reference the source code of that `Activity` during compile time.

This will solve your stated problem.

Comment: The app is getting crashed on executing the above. Here's the logcat :

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown component: com.abc.mainactivity/com.abc.mainactivity.MainActivity

Comment: Post your manifest. Please don't add it as a comment. Just edit your original post and add the complete manifest.

Comment: Posted. Please check.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. These are 2 separate apps. I don't know what you mean by "module", but when you compile an app, you end up with one APK and this APK has one package name. In any case, neither of your packages is called "com.abc.mainactivity" and you don't have an `Activity` named `MainActivity`. None of this makes any sense. Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: In Android Studio, File -> New -> New Module. Thus I have multiple modules in the same application. If you want to use a module's activity in another module, you need to add that module as a dependency in this module. Dependency can be added only if it's a library module. In my example, the module is not a library module. It's an application module. So how would I refer an Activity which lies in a module (which is not a library module)?

Comment: You would need to add this to your manifest. You would need to compile the sources all together and create one application out of it.  Why are you doing this this way? It is very complicated.

Comment: The documentation regarding Android Studio seems to indicate that you can have different modules to support different devices. Although I know that you can share code between modules, it is complicated to generate a single app using gradle from multiple modules. See https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-app-module.html https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/index.html

Comment: Using modules looks like a better way of doing things. So I adopted it :( Isn't there any other way of achieving it via modules?

Comment: I think you will have a lot of problems if you try this. There is no real support, so you will not get any help from other people doing this. Why do you need multiple modules? I do not understand your requirements.

Comment: Its just a way of good coding practice. separating things by modules makes the code clean.

Comment: In this case I disagree. You are building one mobile app. You can use different Java packages to modularize your code. You don't need separate "modules". This makes the whole build and release process much more difficult. My suggestion: don't do it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Somehow I had started. Seems I'll have to rewrite everything avoiding modules :(